# Function templates and derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, derived-class

If this code, why does `foo(d)` call the template function rather than the 'base' function? Is there a way of getting it to call the base function without explicitly writing another function overload?

```
template <class T> void foo(T val)
{
    printf("template called\n");
}

class Base
{
};

void foo(const Base &val)
{
  printf("Base called\n");
}

class Derived : public Base
{   
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    foo(d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `foo<Derived>` is an exact match. You might SFINAE the template function is you don't want overload.

Comment: Your non-templated `foo()` is not an exact match - it requires a conversion from `const Derived &` to `const Base &`).   The templated `foo()` provides an exact match (`foo<Derived>()`).    An exact match (with no type conversion) is preferred over one that requires a type conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does `foo(d)` call the template function rather than the 'base' function?

Because for the template function `foo` `T` is deduced as `Derived`, then it's an exact match. For the non-template one a derived-to-base conversion is required.

You can do it with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae); make the function template works only with types which are not derived from `Base` (or `Base` itself).

```
template <class T> 
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>> foo(T val)
{
    printf("template called\n");
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RYNVAWGN7xJJ3iA8)

Comment: Thanks. For my requirements that's going to cause serious pain as I was hoping to use the template function as a fallback. SFINAE means the template has to explicitly know which objects it mustn't be used on, which sort of turns the dependencies upside-down. I think regular function overloads may be the better approach for me here.

Comment: @Roddy Overloading approach means you have to add another overload which takes `Derived` as parameter; otherwise the function template wins in overload resolution as you've seen.

Comment: Yes, understood. But I'm now planning to ditch the template function entirely, and provide explicit overloaded functions for the cases previously handled by the template.